# C# TcpClient mistakenly reads the response of a previous Write

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream

As a client, I have a queue of messages to send to the server. Each one opens a new TcpClient, Write and Read.

If the server has a delay, and the client reaches its timeout, I close the TcpClient and move to the next message.

However, when writing and reading the next one, I mistakenly read the previous response.

Here's a code that illustrates the problem:

```
        using (TcpClient client1 = new TcpClient(ip, port))
        using (NetworkStream stream1 = client1.GetStream())
        {
            byte[] dataToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message1);
            await stream1.WriteAsync(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);
            await stream1.FlushAsync();
            // The server takes a while to respond. Simulate a timeout in client...
        }

        using (TcpClient client2 = new TcpClient(ip, port))
        using (NetworkStream stream2 = client2.GetStream())
        {
            byte[] dataToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message2);
            await stream2.WriteAsync(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);
            await stream2.FlushAsync();

            byte[] dataToRead = new byte[client2.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = await stream2.ReadAsync(dataToRead, 0, client2.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string messageReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataToRead, 0, bytesRead);
        }
```

The 'messageReceived' gets the response of the first Write rather than the second one.

I tried to set SendTimeout/ReceiveTimeout of the client, but it didn't help.

Is there an elegant way to ignore/avoid the response of the previous Write?

Comment: No.  The response is in the server output buffer so when you connect the second time you are getting the first response.  Why are you doing the FlushAsync?  It is flushing both the input and output stream which is probably why you are loosing the response.

Comment: Where does the "server output buffer" sit?  (Windows level?) Is it possible to configure/clean it?

Removing the FlushAsync didn't affect the result.

Comment: In the server.  Your client code cannot clear the server buffer.  The solution is not to disconnect which is causing the issue.   You are doing thing in parallel which is creating a race condition.  Write, Flush, Read doesn't make any sense.  The Flush is Flushing the TX and RX buffers at the same time a receive message is coming.  So you never get the receive message because it is being cleared by the Flush.

Comment: My problem isn't not-receiving a message. On the contrary - If I add another read in the end, I do get the second respond. My problem is that the disconnection isn't enough - I keep getting the first message first despite the new connection. I tried to remove the flush and to do everything synchronously without all the await/async, but got the same problem. Unfortunately, the server doesn't know that the connection was closed and it's a new connection now.

Comment: When you connect the device may always send the first response.  To get 2nd message you may have to send 2nd command.  Maybe you just have to ignore first message.

Comment: I can't always ignore the first message because the server usually responds before the client timeout, so the problem doesn't happen.

Comment: I can only think of an inelegant solution - The client shall send a unique message prefix (e.g. timestamp or incremental number), which the server must return in its response, so the client can verify it's the same prefix that it just sent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the server. Each connection is independent. A new connection will not see data for an old connection, even if the client and server are the same.

If a *new* connection is getting a response intended for a *different* connection, then that is a bug in the server. It sounds like the server may be sending responses to "whatever clients are currently connected", which is almost always incorrect behavior. Instead, the server should only send responses to the *same* connection that sent the request.